# RoR: form_for is printing the activerecord at the bottom of my page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for

I am creating an extremely basic CMS for my team to enable them to change out page titles and things of that nature. I have cms_pages and cms_pieces. cms_pages indicate what page you will be creating cms_pieces for, therefore cms_pieces belongs_to cms_pages.

From the cms_pages index page I am creating the pages, which I then click through to get to the their show page. On the show page I have created a create form for cms_pieces.

Once cms_pieces have been created I loop through them with an .each method and they are populated below in the form of; their name as the title and its value applied within an input element that will allow my team to update as they like.

This iteration of cms_pieces forms is causing me trouble. Mind you, these cms_pieces update forms are within the view name-convention of cms_pages.

I had tried different rails form helpers to accomplish it, like form_with, but it takes too few arguments to make it accurate like I needed it to. Perhaps I dont understand fully how to use it? From my research it seemed like the new all encompassing way to make rails forms, but I experienced limitations.

So I researched how to aim this form to cms_pieces controller from a cms_pages view and this is what I came up with. It works, but it prints each of the cms_pieces records at the bottom of the page is very ugly and not wanted in the least bit.

*Note, this is within my "Backend" namespace.

```
<%= @cms_pieces.each do |piece|%>
    <div> Edit <%= piece.name %> </div>
    <%= form_for(backend_cms_piece_path(piece), url: backend_cms_piece_path, :method => :patch) do |form| %>
      <% if piece.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(piece.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cms_piece from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% piece.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :input %>
      <%= form.text_field :input, value: piece.input  %>
    </div>

    <div class="field" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: -100;">
      <%= form.label :cms_pages_id %>
      <%= form.text_field :cms_pages_id, value: params[:id] %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: -100;">
      <%= form.label :id %>
      <%= form.text_field :id, value: piece.id %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and then it prints this at the bottom

[ # CmsPiece id: 13, name: "banner title", input: "Banner Stuff?!", cms_pages_id: 12, created_at: "2019-08-23 02:24:24", updated_at: "2019-08-23 03:00:13", #CmsPiece id: 14, name: "banner sub text", input: "Sub Texting up in here", cms_pages_id: 12, created_at: "2019-08-23 03:05:17", updated_at: "2019-08-23 03:05:17" ]

Does any one know whats wrong with my form that its spitting this out in my html??? Or even guide me to a more elegant form helper? I feel like I what I have in the arguments of my form is reduntant, but its the only way I had found to accomplish what I needed.

The reason I have my form set up like this is so that I can pass along the page_id and the piece id to the pieces controller to properly fill out the pieces data. I realize that passing the piece into the form argument should keep the update method straight but it wasnt being passed along so I worked around it by just submitting it with the form fields.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line of code you have used `<%= >`. So it will print each record in loop, please use `<% >` instead of `<%= >`.

Remove `=` from iteration statement will solve the issue.